# loading UItableView in response with uitextfield

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

I am working on a app that loads data from Mysql database. I have 3 view controllers the first one with a textfield to get input and second, master tableview and followed by detailView controller.

When the user input data in the textfield, It search in MySql database and populate it in the tableview. For example, when the user search for recipe name pizza, In the UITexField , the tableview has to populate only pizza recipe. 
i am listing all the recipes in the tableview. I don't know how to make the tableview in respond to the UITextfield input.

NOTE: I am using JSON serialization for loading fast and also  afnetroking for images in detailView.

Comment: whats there in the tableView now.

Comment: You have to find this with some effort about its issue. what have you trying so far about fix this.? there are many similar quetion and it's very good answer to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the delegate method of UITextField named

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return  YES;
}
```

this method is get called when you press the return key after putting the text in UITextField in this method you can call one method say -(void)fetchDataFromMysql

after call to this method your code will look like

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [self fetchDataFromMysql];
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return  YES;
    }
```

in fetchDataFromMysql method retrieve the names of recipes from Mysql store that retrieved names of recipes in the array that you have used to plot the names of the recipes in tableView say "recipeNameAry".

so when the user will enter the search key for example pizza , you will get the recipes of pizza from Mysql ,we store that recipes in the "recipeNameAry" and now the time to update your tableView of recipe names so, after this call the method named "reloadData" for updating tableView , after calling this method your code will look like

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
    {
        [self fetchDataFromMysql];
        [recipeNameTableView reloadData]; 
      //here recipeNameTableView is the name of your tableView.
        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        return  YES;
    }
```

it will update your tableView with the recipes belonging to pizza or whatever.

**NOTE** :- First of all add the UITextFieldDelegate to your .h file like

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface contact : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate>
{
}
@end
```

and in your XIB add the delegate to your UITextField with your FileOwner

Comment: I am sorry but i am not getting you properly what  your trying to say?

Comment: HI shwar, i tried your method as you mentioned. thanks for that.but the uitextfield input 'pizza' is in VC1 and  populate 'pizza' only receipes in tableView thats  in VC2. i cant able to pass the uitextfield input to vc2. I stored as a string when i tried to pass from VC1 too VC2, it returns null.. example shawar, www.example.com/123.php?valuereceipe=%@@,textinputstringhereinVC2fromVC1); can you able to help me please mate

Answer (score 0):

To populate the table, you must have used an array whose data depends upon the selection through textfield from first VC. So first of all grab appropriate data in an array , according to the text in textfield , then using that array, populate the table. To update table at any point , you can use

```
[tblname reloadData];
```

Comment: its worked and it is my fault and i created a segue and allocate texdtfield text to nsstring and transfer that to second viewcontroller as a nsstring. it is working perfect.

Comment: +1 for letting me know , bcoz some time people ,here ask question don't even give feedbacks,and you keep waiting forever to know whether it worked or not. @user1118198